# SWT/Jface cell text not getting saved in Model

Tags: java, swt, jface

I asked a question related to the issue I was having before, but a new one arose. Originally, I wanted the capability of highlighting a row in my table with a single click, and editing a cell with a double click. greg-449 gave me the solution to the problem (getting rid of the FocusCellManager and simply using EditingSupport along with the other classes I had, and setting the editorActivationStrategy to have the MOUSE_DOUBLE_CLICK_SELECTION bit. However, now when I type text into a cell, the text is not saved into my model. On the other hand, when I use the FocusCellManager, the text is indeed saved.

Now, I have to use CellEditors, as there is already a very long list of CellEditors set up for the specific columns. I am not sure if it is possible to use EditingSupport along with CellEditors, or if it necessary at all. I am attaching some snippets.

Relevant Section of DatumTableViewer.java:

```
FocusCellOwnerDrawHighlighter drawHighlighter = new FocusCellOwnerDrawHighlighter(this); //removed this to fix the highlighting issue

final TableViewerFocusCellManager mgr = new TableViewerFocusCellManager(this, drawHighlighter); //removed this to fix the highlighting issue. 

final ColumnViewerEditorActivationStrategy editorActivationSupport = getEditorActivationStrategy();

int tableKeyboardTraversalFeature = getKeyboardTraversalFeature();

TableViewerEditor.create(this, mgr, editorActivationSupport, tableKeyboardActivationFeature);

DatumColumnEmnum[] tableColumnsAsArray = getTableColumnsAsArray();

createTable(this.getTable(), tableColumnsAsArray);

setColumnProperties(properties.getPresentedColumnNames); //properties is passed into constructor

setCellEditors(tableColumnsAsArray); //I think this doesn't work properly without FocusCellManager

DatumCellModifier modifier = new DatumCellModifier(this, properties, myExpressionDataProvider); // myExpressionDataProvider is passed into constructor)

setCellModifier(modifier);

setContentProvider(contentProvider);

setInput(_myDatumList); // myDatumList set before this snippet

}
```

setCellEditors:

```
private void setCellEditors(DatumColumnEnum[] columns)
{
    cellEditor[] editors = new CellEditor[columns.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++){
      DatumColumnEnum columnID = columns[i];
      
      switch(columnID) // cases have been trimmed to shorten this snippet
      {
        case DATUM_ID_COLUMN:
        case DATUM_NUMBER_COLUMN:
        case DATUM_NAME_COLUMN:
          editors[i] = new TextCellEditor(this.getTable());
          ((Text) editors[i].getControl()).setTextLimit(60);
          break;
      }
    }
    this.setCellEditors(editors);
}
```

I suspect these snippets contain the problem, but if not, then please let me know and I'll add the other functions as well.

Comment: `EditingSupport` is just an alternative to using `setCellEditors` and `setCellModifier`, it should not matter much which you use. You can't mix them you either use one or the other.

Comment: does FocusCellManager do anything besides place focus on the cell? Does it interact with the CellEditors?

Comment: I don't know anything about FocusCellManagers as I have never used them.